# How can I render a controller action within a twig extension?

Tags: symfony

I do have a twig extension which has a method that uses another method from a different controller to render a json output via dependency jsonResponse.

How can I render a controller within a twig extension?

The following code below doesn't seem to work, because render() needs a view file instead of a controller. And I am now referencing to a controller.

```
class AreaExtension extends \Twig_Extension {

    public function add()
    {

        $outputJson = $this->container->get('templating')->render(new ControllerReference('CMSCoreBundle:Area:index'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ref = new ControllerReference('CMSCoreBundle:Area:index');
$this->handler->render( $ref, 'inline', $options );
```

Where `$this->handler` is the `fragment.handler` service.

In your case:

```
$outputJson = $this->container->get('fragment.handler')->render(new ControllerReference('CMSCoreBundle:Area:index'));
```

You can find a full example in this symfony twig extension, see:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.1/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/HttpKernelExtension.php#L28
and
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.1/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/HttpKernelRuntime.php#L41

Comment: This works. How would I sent parameters to the controller method? My method looks like public function indexAction($page) {}

Comment: I already found out that I would have to add parameters like so: new ControllerReference('CMSCoreBundle:Area:add', array('param1' => $param1)); Thanks for your help!